# Select rows from dataframe where the difference in time is smallest per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

QUESTION: How do I find all rows in a pandas data frame which have the min time difference when compared to another time of an advice?

Example:

```
   Advicenr Advicehour Setdownnr Zone  Setdownhour
0  A        1          A         16    **2**  <-- zone 16 is closest to advicehour of A
1  A        1          A         16    **3**
2  A        2          A         18      5
3  A        2          A         18      8
4  B        4          B         19      18
5  B        8          B         20    **12** <-- zone 20 is closest to advicehour of B
```

Expected output:

```
   Advicenr Advicehour Setdownnr Zone  Setdownhour
0  A        1          A         16    3  
1  A        1          A         16    2
5  B        8          B         20    12
```

It is not possible that setdownnr is before advice, and it should also not be possible that an advice for a different zone has a timestamp before the previous one ended.

Answer (score 2):

First create column bor absolute differencies between columns and then get `Zone` by minimal difference per groups and select all rows which matched:

```
df['diff'] = df['Setdownhour'].sub(df['Advicehour']).abs()

s = df.set_index('Zone').groupby('Advicenr', sort=False)['diff'].transform('idxmin')
df = df[(s == s.index).to_numpy()]
print (df)
  Advicenr  Advicehour Setdownnr  Zone  Setdownhour  diff
0        A           1         A    16            2     1
1        A           1         A    16            3     2
5        B           8         B    20           12     4
```

Solution without helper column in output:

```
s = df['Setdownhour'].sub(df['Advicehour']).abs()

s1 = df.assign(s = s).set_index('Zone').groupby('Advicenr')['s'].transform('idxmin')

df = df[(s1 == s1.index).to_numpy()]
print (df)
  Advicenr  Advicehour Setdownnr  Zone  Setdownhour
0        A           1         A    16            2
1        A           1         A    16            3
5        B           8         B    20           12
```

Comment: Thanks! Ended up doing this due to difference in the output

`inner_join_tote_nr['avg_diff'] = inner_join_tote_nr.groupby(['Setdownnr', 'Advicehour', 'Zone'])['diff'].transform('min')
s = inner_join_tote_nr.groupby(['Advicenr', 'Advicehour'], sort=False)['avg_diff'].min().reset_index()
selected = pd.merge(s, inner_join_tote_nr, left_on=['Advicenr','Advicehour', 'avg_diff'], right_on = ['Advicenr','Advicehour', 'avg_diff'])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to advice from Jezrael, ended up doing:

```
df['diff'] = df['Setdownhour'].sub(inner_join_tote_nr['Advicehour']).abs()

df['avg_diff'] = df.groupby(['Setdownnr', 'Advicehour', 'Zone'])['diff'].transform('min') 

s = df.groupby(['Advicenr', 'Advicehour'], sort=False)['avg_diff'].min().reset_index() 

selected = pd.merge(s, inner_join_tote_nr, left_on=['Advicenr','Advicehour', 'avg_diff'], right_on = ['Advicenr','Advicehour', 'avg_diff'])
```